# How do I get a table width to stay with in its container?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

*How do I get a table width to stay within its container?*

```
.outerSection:nth-child(4) .innerSection:nth-child(1) .sectionData:nth-child(1) table{ 
    margin:15px 15px 20px 15px;     
    width:100%;     
    max-width:100%; 
}
```

Comment: stay within its container? How would it leave its container? The container's width is based on the width of its children, unless it has a width explicitly set.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or something else with your code?

Comment: try to remove margin, or calculate margin and width that sum of them is 100%. Like width = 90% and margin = 5% will fill entire container (+/- border width)

Comment: thanks it was a problem with the margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table will not overflow the container UNLESS:

```
1. The table has position:absolute;
2. The table has a width greater then 100%
3. The table has a greater pixel width then the container does
4. The table uses margin-left or margin-right
5. The table has a padding, which then you could do width: auto
```

Those are the only simple ways a table could overflow a table. If it is overflowing anyhow, and one of the above 3 conditions are not met, please post your container and table CSS.

A possible to solution to fix yous would be setting the width to auto, or setting the width to 100% and making a 0px margin.

Comment: When you have margin: 15px + width: 100% that will cause #2 to be true.  Example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/7h8cgsjh/

Answer (score 0):

This may have some compatibility issues with some older browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), but you could try:

```
width: calc(100% - 30px)  /*to subtract the 15px on each side*/
```

Alternatively, instead of having that margin you could add padding to its parent container (the .sectionData:nth-child(1) class, or wrap the table in it's own div with padding).  I believe there are a few ways to accomplish what you're looking for.

EDIT:  Here is a fiddle with the 'calc' CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/7h8cgsjh/1/